# Where does and how is the security token serialized when using ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, serialization, token, identity

I would like to know where a security token is serialized when provided from a STS. I am using ASP.NET Identity in a MVC 5 application and have enabled the external login functionality. I get a security token, also known as a authentication token from the STS, but I need to know how the token is serialized and if I have to apply any further security measures to keep the token safe?

Comment: Why would it need to serialize the token?  Once you're authenticated, then there is no need to retain it.  Identity then issues an encrypted cookie to you for authentication purposes.  You're only using the STS for the initial authentication.  The only reason to retain a token is if you're going to access services from the provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the token you acquire from the STS is a bearer token, you want to make sure to use https when talking to the STS to prevent it from being stolen. Bearer tokens can be used by any party holding them to authenticate as you.

As @ErikFunkenbusch already pointed out, the token is persisted as a cookie which basically establishes a session. You only need the token again when getting another token from the STS for another relying party (calling on-behalf-of).